# Свинья от латинского suina

Tags: этимология

Могло ли слово свинья произойти от латинского suina?

Answer (score 1):

В латинском sus, suis - свинья;
suïnus - свиной,sü-cus - влага, сок. Возможность латинских корней имеется, но так же прослеживается и связь с санскритом: sukarâs - свинья, кабан
( sus: м. рождающий, производитель, ж. рождающая).
Но так же существует версия, что название данного животного звукоподражательное (вспомните визг свиньи), которая лично мне более по душе.